# How to drag Grid Stack block to horizontally?

Tags: jquery, gridstack

Default current position is:

```
A B C
D E F
```

I want to move like this horizontally:

```
A E B
C D F
```

But is moves incorrectly like this:

```
A E C
D B F
```

Curret Grid Stack option is:

```
            this.opts = _.defaults(opts || {}, {
                width: parseInt(this.container.attr('data-gs-width')) || 12,
                height: parseInt(this.container.attr('data-gs-height')) || 0,
                itemClass: 'grid-stack-item',
                placeholderClass: 'grid-stack-placeholder',
                placeholderText: '',
                handle: '.grid-stack-item-content',
                handleClass: null,
                cellHeight: 60,
                verticalMargin: 20,
                auto: true,
                minWidth: 768,
                float: false,
                staticGrid: false,
                _class: 'grid-stack-instance-' + (Math.random() * 10000).toFixed(0),
                animate: Boolean(this.container.attr('data-gs-animate')) || false,
                alwaysShowResizeHandle: opts.alwaysShowResizeHandle || false,
                resizable: _.defaults(opts.resizable || {}, {
                    autoHide: !(opts.alwaysShowResizeHandle || false),
                    handles: 'se'
                }),
                draggable: _.defaults(opts.draggable || {}, {
                    handle: (opts.handleClass ? '.' + opts.handleClass : opts.handle ? opts.handle : '') || '.grid-stack-item-content',
                    scroll: false,
                    appendTo: 'body'
                }),
                disableDrag: opts.disableDrag || false,
                disableResize: opts.disableResize || false,
                rtl: 'auto',
                removable: false,
                removeTimeout: 2000,
                verticalMarginUnit: 'px',
                cellHeightUnit: 'px'
            });
```

How to drag Grid Stack block to horizontally?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. Then we can help you and tell you what you did wrong

Comment: Code added in description